# wordpress theme, syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in functions.php on line 118

Tags: function

I tired to fix this line:

```
if ( $_GET['paged'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['paged'] ) ) {
```

on my functions.php  , but with no succes ! i'm really stuck! i get wordpress theme,  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in functions.php on line 118

```
    <?php
/**
*
* @ Release: Me
*
**/
    function get_category_id($cat_name) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'name', $cat_name, 'category' );
        return $term->term_id;
    }

    function kisabaslik($char) {
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );
        $title = mb_substr( $title, 0, $char, 'UTF-8' );
        echo $title;
    }

    function kisaicerik($kisacik) {
        $icerik = get_the_content( $post->ID );
        $icerik = mb_substr( $icerik, 0, $kisacik, 'UTF-8' );
        str_replace( '</strong>', '', $icerik );
        $icerik = str_replace( '<strong>', '', $icerik );
        echo strip_tags( $icerik );
    }

    function the_breadcrumb() {
        global $post;

        if (!is_home(  )) {
            echo '<a href=\'uploadify.php';
            echo get_option( 'home' );
            echo '\'> &raquo; ';
            echo get_option( 'echo_kisasiteadresi' );
            echo '</a>';

            if (( is_category(  ) || is_single(  ) )) {
                echo ' &raquo; ';
                $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                    $cat = $cat[0];
                    $category_id = get_cat_id( $cat->cat_name );
                    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($category_link ) . '" title="' . $cat->cat_name . '">';
                    echo $cat->cat_name;
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo ' &raquo; ';
                }


                if (is_single(  )) {
                    echo '<a href="';
                    the_permalink(  );
                    echo '">';
                    the_title(  );
                    echo '</a>';
                    return null;
                }
            }
else {
                if (is_page(  )) {
                    if ($post->post_parent) {
                        $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                        $anc_link = get_page_link( $post->post_parent );
                        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                            $ancestors = get_ancestors(
                            $output = '<a href="'. $anc_link . '>' . get_the_title( $ancestor ) . "'</a>';
                        }

                        echo $output;
                        the_title(  );
                        return null;
                    }

                    echo ' &raquo; ';
                    echo the_title(  );
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
else {
            if (is_tag(  )) {
                single_tag_title(  );
                return null;
            }


            if (is_day(  )) {
                echo 'Archive: ';
                the_time( 'F jS, Y' );
                echo '</li>';
                return null;
            }


            if (is_month(  )) {
                echo 'Archive: ';
                the_time( 'F, Y' );
                echo '</li>';
                return null;
            }


            if (is_year(  )) {
                echo 'Archive: ';
                the_time( 'Y' );
                echo '</li>';
                return null;
            }


            if (is_author(  )) {
                echo 'Author\'s archive: ';
                echo '</li>';
                return null;
            }


            if ( $_GET['paged'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['paged'] ) ) {
                echo 'Blogarchive: ';
                echo '</li>';
                return null;
            }


            if (is_search(  )) {
                echo 'Search results: ';
            }
        }

    }

    function searchfilter($query) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
        }

        return $query;
    }

    function toplamoynanma() {
        $queryvvv = mysql_query( 'SELECT sum(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key=\'views\'' );
        $rowvvvv = mysql_fetch_array( $queryvvv );
        echo number_format( $rowvvvv[0] );
    }

    function oyhesapla($id) {
        $begen = error_reporting( 0 );
        $begenme = get_post_meta( $id, 'begenme', true );
        $toplamoy3 = $begen + $begenme;
        $toplamoy = $begen - $begenme;
        $begenmeoy = 1 * $begenme;
        $begenoy = 5 * $begen;
        $toplamoy2 = $begenoy + $begenmeoy;
        $fark = $toplamoy * 100 / $toplamoy2;
        $islem = $fark / 10;
        round( $islem, 2 );
        $sonuc = get_post_meta( $id, 'begen', true );
        $sonuc1 = explode( '.', $sonuc );
        $sonuc2 = ceil( $sonuc1[1] / 10 );

        if (!$sonuc2) {
            $sonuc2 = $sonuc / 10;
        }


        if (10 < $sonuc2) {
            $sonuc2 = 40;
        }


        if ($sonuc2 < 1) {
            $sonuc2 = 31;
        }

        echo $toplamoyS;
        echo '<b>' . $sonuc2 . ' / 10 </b><span>( ' . $toplamoy3 . ' members of the game.)</span>';
    }

    function favkon($id) {
        $cookiefav = 'favoricook[' . $id . ']';

        if ($_SESSION[$cookiefav]) {
            echo '<a class="favorileA">Favorite Games.</a>
';
            return null;
        }

        echo '<a class="favorile" onclick="favoriEkle(';
        echo $id;
        echo ');">Add Favorite</a>
';
    }

    function echoyazibegenme($postid) {
        global $tema;

        echo '

<div style=" margin-top:10px; ';

        if ($d == 2) {
            echo 'float:right;';
        }

        echo '">
<div class="oysonuc"></div>

';
        $cookieoysv = 'obegenbegenme' . $postid;
        echo '
    <div class="sYas">
<a id="begen"  onclick="oyver(';
        echo $postid;
        echo ',1);" class="begenButon" title="Be&Auml;Ÿen"></a><div class="begenButonS">';
        echo '<s';
        echo 'pan>';

        if (!get_post_meta( $postid, 'begen', true )) {
            echo '0';
        }
else {
            echo get_post_meta( $postid, 'begen', true );
        }

        echo '</span></div>

<a id="begenme" style="margin-top:0" onclick="oyver(';
        echo $postid;
        echo ',2);" class="begenmeButon" title="Be&Auml;Ÿenme"></a><div class="begenmeButonS">';
        echo '<s';
        echo 'pan>';

        if (!get_post_meta( $postid, 'begenme', true )) {
            echo '0';
        }
else {
            echo get_post_meta( $postid, 'begenme', true );
        }

        echo '</span></div>
</div>


';
        echo '<s';
        echo 'cript>

function oyver(id,is){


if(is==1){

var begenic = $(".begenButonS span").text();

begenic++;

}

if(is==2){

var begenmeic = $(".begenmeButonS span").text();

begenmeic++;

}

$.ajax( {

url: "';
        echo $tema;
        echo 'oyislem.php?islem="+is+"&postID="+id,

success: function(cevap) {
    if(cevap==0){



        $(".oysonuc").fadeIn(500);

        $(".oysonuc").html("<div class=\'uyar\'>The procedure before you did it.</div>").delay(3000);

        $(".oysonuc").fadeOut(500);

    }



    if(is==1 && cevap==1){

    $(".begenButonS span").html(begenic);



    }

    if(is==2 && cevap==1){

    $(".begenmeButonS span").html';
        echo '(begenmeic);

    }

}

});

}

</script>


</div>

';
    }

    function redirect_after_comment($location) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '#yorum';
    }

    function kategori_post_say($id) {
        $count = 31;
        $taxonomy = 'category';
        $args = array( 'child_of' => $id );
        $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
        foreach ($tax_terms as ) {
            $tax_term = [0];
            $tax_term->count;
            $count += ;
        }

        return $count;
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head' );
    $botresim = $tema = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/';
    get_option( 'echo_botswf' );
    $botswf = get_option( 'echo_botresim' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'yeniOyunRes', 147, 119, true );
    add_image_size( 'onerilenOyunlar', 330, 205, true );
    add_image_size( 'mansetOyun', 330, 100, true );
    require_once( TEMPLATEPATH . '/admin/admin-functions.php' );
    require_once( TEMPLATEPATH . '/admin/admin-interface.php' );
    require_once( TEMPLATEPATH . '/admin/theme-settings.php' );
    register_nav_menu( 'kategori-menu', 'Kategori' );
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter' );
    $botresim = register_nav_menu( 'sayfalar', 'Alt K&Auml;&plusmn;s&Auml;&plusmn;mdaki Sayfalar B&Atilde;&para;l&Atilde;&frac14;m&Atilde;&frac14;' );
    get_option( 'echo_botswf' );
    $botswf = get_option( 'echo_botresim' );
    get_category_id( get_option( 'echo_oyunvideo' ) );
    $oyunvideo = add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'redirect_after_comment' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your php is that you are closing the if statement then adding extravariables to nothing. It should look like this:

```
if ( $_GET['paged'] && ! empty( $_GET['paged'] ) ) {
```

Comment: Thanks! but still get the same error  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 118

Comment: whats on line 118 @HamidLmrabet